# How to express absolute cell references in Excel R1C1-style formulas?

Tags: excel-formula, openxml

I want to use a fixed start cell in a range for a SUM function.

I'm working with XSLT 1.0 where I create this:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76" ss:Formula="=SUM(K6:R[-1]C)">
    <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
</Cell>
```

But the the formula appears in Excel as `=SUM('K6':K19)`, and an error message pops up "The formula contains unrecognized text".

I have tried this:

```
=SUM(R[-14]C:R[-1]C)
```

but this is not a good option, because the range can be change.

Comment: You don't say *which* error you get Also this does not seem to be an XSLT question at all, but a pure Excel question.

Comment: @Tomalak im sorry, i have attached the files. The excel put the "cell K6" between '', 'K6' and it can't recognize it.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text on a coding website. Post the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the formulas are in Column `K`, and you want to refer to "K6", then that would be `R6C` (*"row 6, same column"*) in the R1C1 reference style.

So for a range, this:

```
=SUM(R6C:R[-1]C)
```

would mean *"row 6, same column -to- previous row, same column"*.

Comment: I want to avoid specifying the exact row number (like R-14) as the number of rows may change because the query. That’s why I thought if I marked an exact cell because the first five rows will be headers, and the sixth cell will contain the first number.

Comment: @gyuszmok But you always want to start from row 6, don't you?

Comment: My formula does exactly that. `R6C` is an absolute reference. `R[-1]C` is a relative reference.

Comment: looks good at first, thanks for the help.